# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <FirstViewController: 0x2a2c00>

Tags: iphone, ios, transition

I have this problem when I simulate my app, its not an error or a warning but it appears in my console, has anyone ever experienced this before?

Comment: do you make some kind of animation in that view controller ?

Comment: Yes. I have a opening animation that slides to images apart, I have now noticed this error only happens when I am loading code onto the phone.

Comment: the error message suggests you begin a transition but there is a missing call to the corresponding end method.

Comment: Got the same thing. Any solution for this?

Comment: Also looking for a resolution to this

Comment: Sorry I ended up having to move onto something different. after Scott Forbes post I decided not to go any further with it. and now that its been a while since this I forget if i ever did anything to resolve it. Sorry. also I am wondering if ARC (automatic refrence counting) fixes this problem as I have never seen it again since I started using ARC..

Comment: I had similar issue when doing several [navigationController popViewController: animated:] during notifications from MPMoviePlayerController WillExitFullscree and PlaybackDidFinish. So I added a check that my controller is a top controller and message dissapeared from console log.     
    if (mp != NULL) {
        [mp.view removeFromSuperview];
        [mp stop];
        [mp release];
        mp = NULL;
    }
    NSLog(@"top view controller after: %@", [[self navigationController] topViewController]);
    if ([[self navigationController] topViewController] == self) {

Comment: I also looking for a solution to this!

Comment: same here! I've had this issue when presenting a modal view controller

Comment: This answer helped me solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224366/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-warning-when-push-a-view

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In my case, this error occurs when you click two tabs in a tableview very fast.

The result causes wrong titlename, back button disappear. Someone mentioned that when you push a view, `set animated:NO`. The error will disappear but still causes some strange behavior. It pushes two views, then you need to back twice to get back the tableview screen.

Method I tried in order to resolve this problem:

add   `BOOL  cellSelected;`

in `viewWillAppear`   `cellSelected = YES;`

in didselectcell  delegate  `if (cellSelected){cellSelected = NO; do action ; }`

This helps prevent clicking two different cells very fast.

Comment: My guess is some of the wording was hard to understand. I made a few edits to increase the readability.

Answer (score 43):

In my case it happened when I triggered  `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier" sender:self];` within a `UINavigationController` item's `viewDidLoad` method.

Moving it into the `viewDidAppear` method solved the problem.

The reason very likely is that in `viewDidLoad` not all of the fancy animations have already been finished, whereas in `viewDidAppear` everything's done.

Comment: Thanks. I had got myself lost in cavemen era where I was creating every single UI element thro' code. Storyboard stuff is new to me.

Comment: This is what worked for me swift 5 2022 - I was switching root view controllers so I thought that was why.  But I had it in the WILLAPPEAR -> after much searching and researching for an hour I see this and move it to DIDAPPEAR- now everything is roses!  THANK YOU

Answer (score 22):

I have this problem too. I found two solutions to this problem:

1. You can see this solution above.
2. I found subclass from `UINavigationController` where this problem resolved. [Buffered Navigation Controller](https://github.com/Plasma/BufferedNavigationController)

Answer (score 16):

You should run your code in different loop to avoid this

```
 double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            // Put your code here
[self presentViewController:self.yourModalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
```

Comment: A better idea is to enclose the presenting animation inside a `dispatch_async` on main queue. The thing about `dispatch_async` is that it waits until all other animations on main queue are done. it's much better than using a delay because:1- you'll never know if a delay is enough, it depends on your host device 2- you'll end up overdoing the delay and something will lag. try this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[self presentViewController:self.yourModalVC animated:YES completion:nil];});`

Answer (score 12):

I had lot of problem with the same issue. I solved this by this way

1) You're not using `UIViewController's` designated initializer `initWithNibName:bundle:`. Try using it instead of just `init`.

2) set `animated:YES` to a NO, and that solved the problem.
eg. `[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController_Obj animated:NO];`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue using navigation controller and push other controllers to it.
I tried to use [Buffered Navigation Controller](https://github.com/Plasma/BufferedNavigationController) and several other approaches, but it didn't work for me. After spending some time for figuring it out I noticed that this issue occurs if you trying to push new view controller while previous transaction (animation) in progress (about 0.5 sec duration I guess). Anyway, I made quick solution with delegating navigation controller and waiting for previous animation finishes.

Comment: Thank you! Moving my logic to viewDidAppear helped in my situation.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that you do not forget to in -viewWillAppear, -viewDidAppear, -viewDidLoad, -viewWillDisappear, -viewDidDisappear to call proper super method in your overload of that methods.
For example in my case I mismatched method name like this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
 [super viewDidDisappear];
 //some code staff
 ..
}
```

notice that **appear** and **disappear** methods are **mismatched**

Comment: Just spent about two hours debugging this issue and this is what it turned out to be. Calling `super.viewWillAppear()` within `viewDidDisappear()`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It wasn't my only problem, but it helped!

Answer (score 5):

'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for '

Says an animation is started before the last related animation isn't done. So, are you popping any view controller before pushing the new one ? Or may be popping to root ? if yes try doing so without animation i.e. `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

And see if this resolves the issue, In my case this did the trick.

Comment: This is the key: pop or change other viewcontroller transitions at same time.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem that involved rewinding modal dialogs.  Posted the solution here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795258/324479

[Problem]

Nav Controller -> VC1 -Push--> VC2 -PopOver or Modal Segue--> VC3.

VC3 is unwinding back to VC1.

When the Segue from VC2 to VC3 is PopOver and Modal, the unwind ends in a warning: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController"

If the Segue from VC to VC is push, the warning is gone.

[Solution]

It would be great if the unwind logic would take care of this.  Maybe it's a bug, maybe not.  Either way, the solution is to make VC2 (The controller that has the popup) the target of the rewind, then wait for it to finish appearing before popping up the nav controller.  That ensures the rewind (reverse popup) animation has enough time to finish before moving further back.  Even with the animations off, it still has to wait or else you get the error.

Your code for VC2 should be as follows. (Swift)

```
class VC2: UIViewController {
    private var unwind = false
    @IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        unwind = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if unwind {
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue because I was calling a UIPrintInteractionController from a viewController without UITabbar, and neither UINavigationBar. It seems that the UIPrintInteractionController didn't get the correct printInteractionControllerParentViewController.
Implementing the method in the delegate and return the current rootViewController worked for me.

```
    - (UIViewController*)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:(UIPrintInteractionController*)printInteractionController;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

My issue was that I was presenting another VC before my current one finished to be rendered .

Solution was to present my nextVC after a quick delay.

**WHAT YOU SHOULD NOT DO**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    self.present(MyNextVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**WHAT YOU SHOULD DO**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    //Wait until the view finished to be constructed
    perform(#selector(showMyNextVC), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
}

@objc func showCityList() {
    self.present(MyNextVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a delay I would put the code in viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 1):

The situation can occur if you are adding a view with a modal view controller as a sub view. Best to use:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self presentViewController:self.yourModalVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It is basically saying the view life cycle is not streamlined for those viewControllers you are trying to display then.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem when trying to do:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

in a function like `- (void) popUpToLevelTwo;` , and to put a `return;` at the end of function solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I got this same error when not including a call to `[super viewDidLoad:animated]` in my `viewDidLoad` override.

Comment: you maybe mean viewDidAppear? viewDidLoad has no parameters

Answer (score 1):

I also got this at

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I changed the `YES` to a `NO`, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem when i used navigationcontroller's pop method
In my app i use a separate logic for navigation controller,So avoided the use of navigation bar and it is always hidden. Then i use a custom view and notification for handling the backbutton and it's events. notification observers are registered and and not removed. So the notification fires twice, and it creates the above mentioned error. Check your code throughly for getting such fault's

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when I tapped a button from a NIB. It turns out I had accidentally wired the button to send an event to two IBAction methods, each of which did a pushViewController:animated:

Answer (score 1):

I had some logic implemented to wait pushing the `UIViewController` until all data was downloaded. There was an error in this logic which caused to push the `UIViewController` too early while there was still another API call in progress.

It caused the same `UIViewController` to be pushed twice by the `UINavigationController` and gave this warning.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason For message:** This message get displayed if and only if you are pushing/presenting another View controller from `viewWillAppear`,`loadView`,`init` or `viewDidLoad` method of current View Controller

**Way to Remove error Message:** Move your pushing/presenting code to `viewDidAppear` method will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I forget to set Break; after pushing the view in a switch statement!

Like here:

```
case 1:{

        SomeViewController *someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:Nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
        [someViewController release];
    }

        break; //Forgetting to set break here:
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind the error " Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions"  is when you navigate | segue twice at the same time

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05(or as required) target:self
selector:@selector(your_selector_method_to_push_the_view) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run into this if you try to dismiss a UIViewController before it is finished loading.

I had this message in the console and was focusing entirely on the UIViewController that was presenting the new UIViewController, without success. I finally discovered the problem was in the UIViewController I was presenting was dismissing itself because the user wasn't logged into their account.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one for me:
I've overridden

```
override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

without overriding:

```
override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

in my window root navigation controller.
then a child navigation controller complained when pushing another view controller with the above mentioned warning. 
The warning wasn't the worst,
the big problem was, that there the delegate of the child navigation controller weren't called anymore.
weired.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was fetching `NSData` from `NSURL` inside '`viewDidLoad`' method.