# "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" warning when push a view in a modal way in XCode 4 with Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

After some research on the web without success, I come here to ask you the question about my warning.

Actually, I have a view V1 with a navigation controller and I want to push a modal view V2 when V1 has finished loading.
So I use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method (I'm using storyboard).
Here is my code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showConnexionViewSegue" sender:self];
```

And when I compile, I got this warning:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x6849b30>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It sounds like you may be performing the segue in `-viewWillAppear:` thus generating two `-viewWillAppear:` messages without 2 corresponding `-viewDidAppear` messages.

Try performing the segue in `-viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I had encountered this by performing the segue in `-viewDidLoad`, and I was working around it by calling `performSegue` inside a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with a delay of 0, but that was messy. This fix allows me to call `performSegue` directly in `-viewDidAppear:`. Thanks!

Comment: Had a pop call in viewdidload. Moved the call into viewdidappear, and it fixed it for me.

Comment: `-viewDidAppear:` is a method on `UIViewController` that can be overridden in your `UIViewController` subclasses. The `-viewDidAppear:` message is sent to your view controller once the view has appeared on screen.

Comment: You are the best. Saved my day. Thax a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, but what I had done is on a `UIViewController` I had linked a Segue from a `UIButton` and also coded it into a `nextBtnPressed:` function, so I was actually pushing two new `UIViewControllers` on the one button press. Limiting it to just the one segue fixed it. But it took some investigating to see that I had done this double up.

Answer (score 5):

'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for '

Says an animation is started before the last related animation isnt done.
So, are you popping any view controller before pushing the new one ?
Or may be popping to root ? if yes try doing so without animation 
i.e. [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

And see if this resolves the issue, In my case this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for this are manifold and are very specific to the context and the programming. For example, what I was doing was

1. initialising a sound file, playing it (asynchronously) for 1.4 seconds,
2. making an image move across the screen using animation timed to last 1.4 seconds and,
3. with a timer set to 1.4 seconds after step 2, pushing a viewcontroller.

What i discovered is that if I DO NOT have the instructions for these 3 steps one after the other (if I mix them up), then I get the error "Unbalanced calls...". Also, if I time the push of the viewcontroller to less than 1.4 seconds, I get the message as well.

So, check that the sequence and timing of your program instructions are correct.