# pushViewController not working when animated:NO

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm not sure what exactly broke in my app, but when I now try to change to a view controller, it won't work when animated:NO. When animated:YES, it works but displays the error:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions
```

Here's my (fairly simple) code for calling it:

```
JViewerViewController *viewer = [[JViewerViewController alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewer animated:NO];
```

I did an NSLog on the navigation controller, the viewer an the visible view controller. Interestingly, it counts the viewer as the visible view controller.

Comment: Are you using tab bar controller

Comment: Please check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224366/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-warning-when-push-a-view

Might already solve your problem.

Comment: you might be calling a UIView on viewWillAppear or some similar methods(While loading View).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs when you try and display a new viewcontroller before the current view controller is finished displaying. You can reproduce it by navigating in viewWillAppear.

Basically you are trying to push two view controllers onto the stack at almost the same time. 
 Push one at a time on to the stack and check on exit from the current view whether there are any queued detail views which need displaying.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
JViewerViewController *viewer = [[JViewerViewController alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewer animated:NO];
```

call that method inside the ViewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
ViewerViewController *viewer = [[JViewerViewController alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewer animated:NO];
}
```