# PopToRootViewController displays an unbalanced message inside a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iOS application that has two tabs with navigation controllers on them. One of the tabs has a logout button on it. The logout button invokes a function that performs a `popToRootViewController` on the navigation controller on the other tab. This will display the following message in the debugger:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   <*UIViewController*>.

This message does not appear if I change to the tab that I am trying to clear, and then call `popToRootViewController` or if I manually loop through all the view controllers in that navigation controller and call `popViewController`. The `animated` flag of `popToRootViewController` is set to `false` in both cases. Is this functionality intended?

Comment: Could you make your question a little more clear? Perhaps post some code? I can't understand the description of your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I know this is a three years old post..but did you find a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the popRootViewAnimation to "false", hope it'll resolve your issue.

self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

If you want some details about your issue, then check this link:

["Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for DetailViewController" when pushing more than one detail view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller)

Comment: Did you check the link given above?
try this link as well. Try all the solutions given in these links. I hope it will work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919616/keep-getting-unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-viewcont