# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <BTSViewController: 0x865c520>

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I am facing this error, when i come back to my old View after visiting a new View (On click of Back Button on navigationBar)

**First:** On click of searchBar, i am visiting a new View which contains searchBar in place of `UINavigationBar` (`UINavigationBar` is hidden in new View)..

***Here is code snippet, which navigates to new View after clicking searchBar...***

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{
    BTSViewController *Obj = [[BTSViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"BTSViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Obj animated:NO];
}
```

**Second:** on click of cancel button in searchBar i am going back to my previous View & in 
`viewWillDisappear` method i am doing `setNavigationBarHidden:NO`

***Here is code snippet, which comes back to previous View after clicking Cancel button in UISearchBar...***

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

I am navigated to my previous view but `UINavigationBar` is hidden and shows `Unbalanced call error...` in my Log.

**Thanks in advance !!**

Comment: post the code of your previous viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad:` method because in `viewDidLoad:` method not all of the fancy animations have already been finished so your app crahsed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you get this type of error with Two Reasons.

1. If you pushed more then one `UIViewController` at a same time.
2. In your `ViewController.m`'s  `viewDidLoad:` method in not all of the fancy animations have already been finished so your app crahsed

I suggest If you add some Fancy Animations code in `viewDidLoad:` method then just replace that type of code from `viewDidLoad:` to  `viewDidAppear:` and Also maintain Queue of your viewControllers..

i hope this answer helpful to you...

Comment: I am not pushing 2 views at same time also i am not using any animation in my class..

Comment: i am not say that you push two class at a time but here its push two times i have this type of problem occured before 6 months in which i push viewcontroller when user enter text in textfield and click return key at that time i push viewcontroller and its push two time after i solved with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088465/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-detailviewcontroller

Comment: you can also check this which i search before 1 hour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809593/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-firstviewcontroller-0 i hope its helpful to you.. :)