# "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for" when navigating front and back using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am stuck with this .Its is simply printing in my console when I navigate front and back .Can anyone tell why this is occurs.

In viewController1

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCon2 animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Did you search for it? Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809593/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-firstviewcontroller-0?rq=1

Comment: Support your question with code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You may be creating two viewcontrollers and pushing it on the same segue action/button press.

Comment: I think you are doing it in viewWillAppear.Do it in viewDidapper