# iOS - Transition with scene error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

I am working on an application, which uses cocos2D. It works very well, but I have a problem during some transitions. Sometimes, I get an error when I use:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Menu scene]];
```

I get:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyViewController>
```

I see with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809593/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-firstviewcontroller-0) link that there is for example two same view controllers at the same time, or other things like this. I also see that I must use:

`setAnimated:NO`

to solve this problem. But I can't with a `CCScene`.

How could I fix this problem please?

Thanks for your help!

Additional code :

```
WillExit:^{
    // This code is called when exiting the portal                                
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Menu scene]];
    //[[CCDirector sharedDirector].view setanimated:NO]; I try some things like this...
 }];
```

Comment: Could you show some more code? Is it by any chance possible that oyu are trying to replace a scene, while another transition is in progress?

Comment: It is hard to show some more code, because this problem appears when I exit from a download module. I add some code, look. That's why I would set animated to NO, to avoid this problem of transitions.