# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I'm making a transition in the TabBarController by using the TabBarControllerDelegate method `shouldSelectViewController`. I'm getting the following warning

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x1804dcf0>.
```

I believe that this is because the line where I'm calling `viewWillAppear(true)` (marked with *** below) on the destination ViewController (this to smooth the transition to the new controller).

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886096/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-uitabbarcontroller-0x) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809593/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-firstviewcontroller-0) that are similar but not exactly the same. I think i should tell the current View Controller on screen that he will be removed (as this warning started to appear when added the **marked line**), but I'm not sure how.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    let controllerIndex: Int = find( (self.viewControllers as! [UIViewController]), viewController)!

    if(controllerIndex == tabBarController.selectedIndex) {
        return false
    }

    // Get the views
    let fromView: UIView = tabBarController.selectedViewController!.view
    let toView: UIView = (tabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewController])[controllerIndex].view

***
    // Tell the destination view controller know it will appear on screen
    (tabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewController])[controllerIndex].viewWillAppear(true)
***

    let viewSize = fromView.frame
    let scrollRight = controllerIndex > tabBarController.selectedIndex;

    // Add the to view to the tab bar view.
    fromView.superview?.addSubview(toView)


    // Position it off screen.
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    toView.frame = CGRectMake(
        scrollRight ? screenWidth : -screenWidth,
        viewSize.origin.y,
        screenWidth,
        viewSize.size.height
    )

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        fromView.frame = CGRectMake(
            scrollRight ? -screenWidth : screenWidth,
            viewSize.origin.y,
            screenWidth,
            viewSize.size.height
        )

        toView.frame = CGRectMake(
            0,
            viewSize.origin.y,
            screenWidth,
            viewSize.size.height
        )
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        if(finished) {
            fromView.removeFromSuperview()
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = controllerIndex
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```